# Is it safe to build with -fsigned-char with Android NDK?

Tags: android, c, embedded, android-ndk, arm

For consistency with other platforms, I need to use `signed char` in some native code I'm working on. But by default on Android NDK `char` type is `unsigned`.

I have tried to explicitly use `signed char` type but it generates too many warnings `differ in signedness` when string constant/library functions are involved, so I'm looking to build my code with `-fsigned-char`.

I'm now trying to anticipate problems regarding Android ARM [ABI and API](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html) when `-fsigned-char` is used, but I can't find any problem yet.

In [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture
ABI (AAPCS)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/index.html), 7.1.1 Arithmetic Types, and [C Library ABI for the ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0039b/index.html) , 5.6 inttypes.h, `char` is said to be `unsigned`.

Did you know if there Will be some trouble when using C library (others libraries available on Android) when `-fsigned-char` is enabled in Android NDK?

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered this issue tonight. `char` is treat as `signed` on x86, but changed to `unsigned` when run on Android device. This make my JNI libs don't work properly.

After setting `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fsigned-char` in Android.mk, my program works! Currently I found no side effect. Thanks.

Comment: While this "worked" for me as well.  It did seem to break viewing strings in the Android Studio debugger.  :(