# Implicit type conversion and different behavior between x64 and arm64

Tags: c++, gcc, arm

I'm facing a weird issue when testing my software on arm64.

I've written a bit of code to reproduce the issue :

```
char c;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
   c = i;
   int a = c * 10;
   sum += a;
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it on Windows (built with Visual Studio 2017) or Ubuntu x64 (gcc 9.3.0-17) I have the following results :

```
0
10
...
1260
1270
-1280
-1270
-20
-10
sum=-1280
```

if I run the same code on Ubuntu arm64 (gcc 9.3.0-17), I have different results :

```
0
10
...
1260
1270
1280
1290
...
2540
2550
sum=326400
```

I don't know if there is some extra optimization in gcc on arm64 (using -O3) or if there is some issue I don't see ? Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you should check whether `char` is signed or unsigned type on arm platform instead of assuming it. Note that `char` is a distinct type to `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: It's not the hardware; it's the compiler that decides signedness and overflow behavior.

Comment: @alfC I think the OP has *not* converted to `int` first, so as to reproduce the issue. Their 'real world' code may be rather more subtle/complex.

Comment: @alfC Also, in your suggestion, the `static_cast<int>(c)` will be too late - the assignment and (likely) overflow will already have happened in the previous statement.

Comment: `char` can be signed or unsigned, and on ARM it's usually unsigned by default whereas most architectures use signed char by default: [Why unsigned types are more efficient in arm cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3093669/995714), [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714), [is char signed or unsigned by default on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20576300/995714). In gcc the signness of char can be changed with `-funsigned-char` or `-fsigned-char`

Comment: @alfC -- the compiler converts the value of `c` to `int` to do the multiplication. Integer types get promoted at least to `int` or `unsigned int` for arithmetic operations. That `static_cast` just tells the compiler to do what it would have done anyway. (Well, except in the somewhat perverse case where `char` is the same size as `int` and unsigned).

Comment: Thanks @phuclv, that was exactly the option I needed.

Answer (score 5):

The `char` data type can be either *signed* or *unsigned*. In the case of the former (as seems to be the case when targeting x64), the `c = i` statement will cause overflow on the 129<sup>th</sup> iteration of the `for` loop (the maximum value for a `signed char` is 127) and the value it is being assigned has 'wrapped round' to a negative value.

However, when targeting arm64, your compiler appears to use an *unsigned* `char` type (with a range of `0` thru `255`), so there is no overflow in that statement and the arithmetic proceeds 'as expected'.

---

To confirm (or otherwise) the above diagnosis, just check the value of the `CHAR_MAX` constant (defined in the `<climits>` header file) in your different build environments.

Comment: That's exactly the issue! char was unsigned by default. Thanks for pointing that out. I learned something today.

Answer (score -1):

`char` is signed **by standard**.
However, ARM decided to make it unsigned **by default** decades ago.

It's that simple.

Comment: The C++ standard leaves it implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned: [basic.fundamental (7)].  ARM is perfectly compliant here.

Comment: @NateEldredge `char` is unsigned on all toolchains for ARM. It was ARM's decision.

Comment: Sure.  I'm disagreeing with your first sentence, that `char` is signed "by standard".

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right in that. I have to admit that it was new to me.

Answer (score -3):

`char` is represented by 8 bit and it is signed. You can store 0-127, after that first bit is interpreted as a negative number. Maybe it is better to use `uint8_t` or similar instead of `char`.

Comment: You can't store 128 in a signed, 8-bit char type. The range is -128 thru +127.

Comment: You know about editing your own posts, right?

Comment: `char is represented by 8 bit and it is signed` **that's not correct**. `char` is represented by `CHAR_BIT` bits (which can be larger than 8) and is a signed or unsigned type depending on implementation. And your answer doesn't explain why the results are different between 2 platforms

Comment: The overflow is not a problem, it's even intended in that case. Windows and Linux x64 behaved correctly. And changing the code was not possible, it's too widely use.